# MasterPage in ASP.net and Bootstrap change the active page

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i have a **masterpage** like so in asp.net

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="store.aspx">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.aspx">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

i am using bootstrap to style it but i want the pages to be highlighted when i click on for example  store that should be highlighted. but since my `active` is only in `default.aspx` it only highlights that 
is there way to fix this.

Comment: You can create the menu as a string in code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    var url = window.location;
                    $('.navbar .nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
                    $('.navbar .nav li a').each(function () {
                        if (this.href == url) {
                            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                });
```